# find and sort command with "k" arguments

Tags: bash

I have this command which finds all files under /usr/bin and /usr/sbin and sorts them by filename in order

e.g.

```
/usr/bin/zypp-CheckAccessDeleted
/usr/bin/zypper
/usr/sbin/zypp-refresh
/usr/sbin/zypp-refresh-wrapper
```

I'm a bit confused by the `-k4,4` - I thought I should be putting in `-k3,3` as the zypp* files listed above are in column 3 but that does not work - could someone explain the way the k argument works a bit clearer please ?

```
find /usr/bin /usr/sbin -type f -maxdepth 1 | sort -t/ -k4,4
```

Answer (score 1):

Column 1 is everything before the first delimiter, which here is empty because the line starts with the delimiter (`/`).  Column 2 is `usr`, 3 is `[s]bin`, 4 is the `zypp*` you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In your filenames, the first "field" is of zero length because your filenames start with `/`:

```
 / usr / bin / zypper
^  ^     ^     ^
1  2     3     4
```